# C++ Template: What happens if we put wrong thing in our template class

Tags: c++, templates

C++ templates allow we put whatever in our objects with template arguments. However, if our template arguments use functions/variables which belong to certain types, how do we check?

```
template<typename BarType>rguments

class Foo {

public:

     Foo() { bar = new BarType() }

private:

     BarType * bar;

}

Foo<Bar> …
```

BarType could be anything derived from a Bar superclass.

What happens if we invoke some functions which only belong to Bar in our Foo class? What happens if we pass non-BarType? Do we have anyway to check?

Comment: *Huh?* ... No really, can you please clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get a compile-time error if your templated code makes reference to members that the actual parameter doesn't provide when you try to instantiate the template. So don't worry, you won't be able to break anything.

Think of templates as a code-generation mechanism. Whether the generated code actually makes sense can sometimes only be determined when you actually try it.

Comment: But do note that this is done on a per-function basis, not for the entire class template at once.

Comment: @Ben (I'm completing what Ben said.) What he means, is that if a certain function in the template is not ever called, it won't compile. This means you could write complete rubbish in there and the program will still compile, because it never actually cares to check functions you don't call. This is not true for normal classes, where functions get compiled (checked) even if you don't use them.

Comment: @Paul: That's not exactly true either.  See also: *two-phase lookup* and *dependent names*.

Comment: @Paul: Also, it can't be "complete rubbish", it still has to be syntactically correct C++. It's obvious, I just want to be clear about this.

Answer (score 2):

Given the class template `TempFoo` below, you see that it calls the `example` function of the templated `T` type in its constructor. The first two types work because they both define `example`; the third doesn't.

```
template<typename T>
class TempFoo
{
    void TempFoo() {
        T obj;
        obj.example();
    }
};

class First {
    void example() {}
};

class Second {
    void example() {}
};

class Third {
};

int main()
{
     TempFoo<First> f; // works
     TempFoo<Second> s; // works
     TempFoo<Third> t; // doesn't

}
```

Comment: huh?? You should revisit the intended code, as the second line in `main` will not compile (`Seond`, missing `c`) but the third line will compile (contrary to what the comment indicates)

Comment: @David Oh, so sorry for that. :(

Comment: No probs. Just thought that if I left a comment you would be notified and get around to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you're giving in the tempalte parameter list is simple a place place holder. Compiler will repalce with appropriate types according to the type of object which is used to instantiate the template class. A compile-time error will be appear if the object doesn't satify the operations done in the functions. Also it's a good practice to use 'T' as place holder.

Comment: I don't think there's specific reason for that. It's a kind of naming conventon use to mention single parameterized template classes or functions. If multiple types are used, the usual notation is like T1, T2 etc. But again no strings attached. You can give any names. In Stroustrup sample's it's specified like typename Container some places. It's a choice according to the situation. I was conveying a standard notation

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to ensure that the template parameter derives from the base class:

```
template<typename BarType>
class Foo 
{
    // ...
    ~Foo() { Bar* p = (BarType*)0; }
};
```

The compiler will type-check the assignment, generating an error if `Bar` isn't an unambiguous supertype of `BarType`, and then optimize away the unused local variable.

Comment: Wouldn't `dynamic_cast` be better?

Comment: @Paul: No.  We're checking a compile-time type (the typename template parameter), not a dynamic type..